# Gallery with bigger previews "in place"

Tags: javascript, css

My aim is to do a thumbnail gallery which will enlarge thumbnail in a new row after the thumbnail has been clicked [Edited for clarity]:

[image]

I am not sure how to do it properly (if there is a proper way). How would you conceptually approach this task?

Flexbox seems to be nice for the first part, but then add cell on calculated position by JS OR split the flexbox into two? And in every case redo everything completely in there was a resize?

A help would be also to know how this kind of gallery is called, because I was unable to find any info on Google. Thank you!

Comment: _"if there is a proper way"_ - rule #1 (or #7) of web development, there is no "proper" way. There are many ways, some are better than others.

Comment: :) I meant if there isn't a catch causing this to be impractical on phones or something else. I am not sure if that deserves a -1.

Comment: You got no downvote from me. Although the lack of a [mcve] might prompt people to downvote.

Comment: I see, thanks. I was thinking about it, but since I am only web developer of intermediate skills, I thought I ask about the whole idea first. I don't need the code, just the overall idea.

Comment: SO is not really the place to ask for broad solutions, opinions or libraries. That's probably why you got a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example showing how a container could use `display:flex;` to show a number of `div.item` as pictures in a gallery.

Each of such `div.item` gets attached an handler for the click event, that will clone, populate and attach to dom the template defined to represent a preview.

The preview will show a bigger picture of the thumbnail clicked and some further details that the demo just limits to the item index number. Such bigger picture must be defined in the attribute `data-original-image-url` of the img thumbnail.

I was inspired to this question [Gallery with bigger previews "in place"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096795/gallery-with-bigger-previews-in-place/72096982) to craft the trick needed to determine the last item of a given row in a flex container.

Consider that the pictures url are fake here so the demo won't show any picture but just broken urls. I faked the size of items setting a arbitrary different width for each of them and setting the height fixed in a css class.

```js
//Add click event handler to every div.item in any .gallery
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery > div.item');
for(let item of items){  
  item.addEventListener('click', onItemClick);
}

/*
 When an item gets clicked,
 It shows a preview, bound to the item clicked, on the next line
*/
function onItemClick(event){      
    
   //the clicked item
   //(currentTarget retrieves the item that had the listener not the actual element clicked)
   //so in this case it will be always the div.item (never the picture itself)
   clickedItem = event.currentTarget;
    
  //determines the index (1 based) of the clicked item relative to its container
  const itemIndex
  = Array.from(clickedItem.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.item')).indexOf(clickedItem) + 1;  
  
  //removes all .preview elements inside the parent of the clicked item
  clickedItem.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.preview').forEach( (o, i) => {
    o.remove();
  });
  
  //retrieves the url for the bigger picture of the item clicked
  let urlBiggerImage = clickedItem.querySelector('img').getAttribute('data-original-image-url');
  //retrieves the last item in the row where the item clicked lays
  let lastItemOfRow = getLastItemOfRow(clickedItem);
  
  //retrieves the html template for the preview
  const template = document.getElementById("template_preview");
  //clones the template to prepare the node as a concrete preview for the current item
  const preview = template.content.cloneNode(true);  
  //sets the img src of the preview using the value of this item.data[original-image-url]
  preview.querySelector('img').src = urlBiggerImage;  
  //sets the description of the preview
  preview.querySelector('.col:nth-child(2) p').innerText = `You selected the item n.${itemIndex}`;  
  //appends the preview item after the last item in the row where item clicked lays
  lastItemOfRow.after( preview );  
}

/*
Retrieves the last item in the row (of the flexbox container)
given an item determining the row to examine
Inspired by:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096795/gallery-with-bigger-previews-in-place/72096982
*/
const getLastItemOfRow = (item) => {    
  
  const grid = item.parentElement;      
  const gridItems = Array.from(grid.querySelectorAll('.item'));  
  const itemIndex = gridItems.indexOf(item);      
  const baseOffset = item.offsetTop;
  
  let breakIndex = gridItems.findIndex(item => item.offsetTop > baseOffset) -1;        
  breakIndex = (breakIndex < 0) ? itemIndex : breakIndex;
  
  return gridItems[breakIndex];
}
```

```css
.gallery{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px 10px;  
  padding: 10px;  
  border: solid 1px gray;      
  /*Here you can define an arbitrary width for the container*/
  width: 430px;
}

.item{
  display: block;  
  height: 50px;
  background: red;  
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;  
  cursor: pointer;  
}

.item > img{
  height: 50px;
}

.preview{
  border: solid 1px black;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.preview > .col{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bigger {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<template id="template_preview">
  <div class="preview">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="bigger" src=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>You selected the picture n:</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</template>

<!-- You can have many .gallery container -->
<div class="gallery">

  <!-- Each .item will count as an item with preview -->
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/1.jpg" title="1" style="width: 100px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/1.jpg"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/2.jpg" title="2" style="width: 70px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/2.jpg"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/3.jpg" title="3" style="width: 180px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/3.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/4.jpg" title="4" style="width: 220px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/4.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/5.jpg" title="5" style="width: 40px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/5.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/6.jpg" title="6" style="width: 80px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/6.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/7.jpg" title="7"  style="width: 50px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/7.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/8.jpg" title="8" style="width: 50px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/8.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/9.jpg" title="9" style="width: 50px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/9.jpg"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/10.jpg" title="10" style="width: 50px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/10.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/11.jpg" title="11" style="width: 50px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/11.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/12.jpg" title="12" style="width: 50px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/12.jpg"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/13.jpg" title="13" style="width: 80px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/13.jpg"/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/img/14.jpg" title="14" style="width: 150px;" data-original-image-url="/img/bigger/14.jpg"/>
  </div>
      
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It is an alternative approach, but since I plan on using images of even widths (aligned automatically to fit the row), this would probably cause too much resizing and jumping around. In my case it would be probably confusing to the user, but it still may be usable solution for someone else.

Comment: actually the container has `display:flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` so that the items will be distributed inside keeping the defined gap row and gap column (10px). Plus the container has a padding to keep items well distanced from its borders. There's no better solution than that to style a gallery having differently sized items inside. You may only discard the solution I picked to highlight the item selected. I chose the :active condition but you needed a different strategy that wasn't perfectly clear: `gallery which will enlarge thumbnail after click in a new row`.

Comment: there's no new row you are clicking on inside the picture you showed. All I can see is a list of ordered items that after an unknown event shows a different screen with an added line detailing the box titled B. So i suppose the B item was clicked (not a new row was clicked) and it adds a new line after the one containing the B item, to show the B item details. That's pretty hard with flex because it seems hard to control where is the next item breaking the row (afaik). If I had a clue I would change my answer.

Comment: And I get now your sentence just needed a comma or better rephrasing: `gallery which will enlarge thumbnail in a new row after the thumbnail was clicked`

Comment: I see, I don't mind the :active condition, that is perfectly fine as a demonstration. I also edited the original text as you proposed - thanks. If I won't be able to find perfect&easy solution I might end up with either this flex-based one perhaps doing everything in JS by shifting ordinary divs around.

Comment: I completed my incomplete answer.. now the demo should fulfill the exact scenario you requested in your question. It will add an item occupying a full row in the flex container just after the last item in the row where the clicked item lies. Such preview item is defined separately in a template element in html and will just need to be populated with data inside the js click event handler on gallery items. I was very interested to this question because it went further than what it seemed at the beginning. I never went that far with display flex.

Comment: Wow, I am amazed! That is pretty much exactly it. Thank you very much! Answer very gladly accepted.

Comment: Just one small fix: In your JS code there should be something like `getElementsByTagName('img')[0].` right before `getAttribute('data-original-image-url');`. Otherwise it works perfectly as it is.

Comment: do you mean this part: `preview.querySelector('img').src = urlBiggerImage;`? that's the section in charge of preparing the preview element starting from the template defined in the html. I didn't use a very proper strategy because I was addressing a custom scenario for the demo. Anyway `querySelector('img')` is equivalent to `getElementsByTagName('img')[0]`

Comment: No, I meant this line `let urlBiggerImage = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-original-image-url');` - when clicked, the currentTarget is a div (at least in my Firefox) and the data-original-image-url attribute is found in its child img, so the original line always returns null.

Comment: oh yes it was a terrible mistake. `.currentTarget` returns the element that had the event handler attached (div.item) and not the element that actually fired the event (the picture). I didn't test the img src attribute before submitting the answer and indeed it was null. Now I edited my answer and its demo works correctly. Thanks for pointing out.